# Python - Same xpath in selenium and lxml different results

Tags: python, selenium, lxml

I have this site http://www.google-proxy.net/ and i need to get first proxy's ip:port.

```
br = webdriver.Firefox()
br.get("http://www.google-proxy.net/")
ip = br.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='odd']/td[1]").text; time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 1))
port = br.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='odd']/td[2]").text; time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 1))
```

and it works fine. But now i want to do the same with lxml

```
page = requests.get(proxy_server)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(page.text)
ip = root.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']/td[1]/text()")
port = root.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']/td[1]/text()")
```

and i get empty lists. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like 'odd' classes are added by Javascript in this site.

Selenium, as it runs the browser, executes the Javascript, so you have the expected class.

requests library will not execute JS, so there's no 'odd' class.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Selenium` to open `http://www.google-proxy.net`, **JavaScript is enabled**. In this case, JavaScript adds the classes `odd` and `even` to the `tr` elements.

The `requests.get` method loads the HTML from `http://www.google-proxy.net` **without JavaScript enabled**. So the classes `odd` and `even` are not added to the `tr` elements, and your `XPath/lxml` functionality doesn't select anything. To replicate this behaviour you can use JavaScript switcher plugins eg [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en). This allows you to easily load webpages without JavaScript enabled.