# Finding an element by xpath - lxml and Selenium result in different outputs for the same expression

Tags: selenium, xpath, lxml

This is the first of a couple of questions about the different ways lxml and Selenium handle xpath expression. (While somewhat similar, this, I believe, [is different from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34705159/9448090)).

So let's start with the simpler question.

Here's the string:

```
my_str = """
<div class="container">

   <div class="24">
        <div class="25">forget me</div>
        <div class="26">a target </div>
   </div>
    <div class="27">very desired
        <div class="28">whatever</div>
        <div class="29">another target</div>
    </div>
    <div class="30">go home
         <div class="31">Nothing here</div>
         <div class="32">somewhat desired</div>
    </div>
 </div>
"""
```

And here's the xpath expression:

```
simple_expression = "//*[contains(text(), 'target')]"
```

Now let's see how this is handled by lxml:

```
import lxml.html
root = lxml.html.fromstring(my_str)

e = root.xpath(simple_expression)
for entry in e:
    print(entry.text)
```

This produces the desired output:

> a target
>
> another target

Over to Selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome()
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=my_str))

e2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(simple_expression)
print(e2.text)
```

The output this time is only

> a target

So - first, why is that the case? Second, how does one make Selenium generae the same output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have used `find_element_by_xpath` and it will return single element and first item found.

You need to use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` to get all the elements.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(simple_expression)
```

### Here is your full code.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
my_str = """
<div class="container">

   <div class="24">
        <div class="25">forget me</div>
        <div class="26">a target </div>
   </div>
    <div class="27">very desired
        <div class="28">whatever</div>
        <div class="29">another target</div>
    </div>
    <div class="30">go home
         <div class="31">Nothing here</div>
         <div class="32">somewhat desired</div>
    </div>
 </div>
"""

simple_expression = "//*[contains(text(), 'target')]"
driver = Chrome()
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=my_str))

e2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(simple_expression)
for e in e2:
 print(e.text)
```

### Output:

```
a target
another target
```

Comment: Wow! So THAT was the problem? And here I was thinking I stumbled across a profound structural problem and it was all about a dropped `s`! I must be (going) blind... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the lxml case you are getting a list of nodes and iterating through them.

```
e = root.xpath(simple_expression)
for entry in e:
    print(entry.text)
```

Where as in selenium you are using `find_element` which will return the first matching element. That's why you are getting only one node. Try changing that that to `find_elements` and iterate the same way you did it in the lxml.

**Sample Code:**

```
e2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(simple_expression)
for e in e2:
 print(e.text)
```